# What is the original use case of SIGEMT?

Tags: unix, signals

I can not find any documentation or code that describe what SIGEMT was originally invented for.
All the code I can find (e.g. with debian code search) seems to just handle it like all the other signals that terminate the process or just map the signal number to a name (or name to number).
From the short descriptions it looks like this is used in some kind or instruction emulation that has a kernel and a user space part. Is there any software that actually uses this?
I could find code in the linux kernel that might emit the signal, but it's not documented either.

Comment: Maybe [this info](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/why-do-i-get-run-time-error-sigemt/15957) may help?

Comment: I don't really know what that codechef thing uses for execution, but that thread makes it looks like something very confused. And it's likely something that didn't even exist when SIGEMT was introduced into unix.